# logut from navigation drawer to login activity in android

Tags: android

I had getting problem in navigation drawer activity, i had created my android project with login activity and navigation drawer activity but when i want to logout from navigation drawer to login activity. i didn't come on it, i had tried everything. following is my code. please help me to solve this.

activity_home.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

NavigationDrawer.xml

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_vehicle_enq"
        android:title="Vehicle Enquiry" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_my_vehicle"
        android:title="My Vehicles" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_my_rides"
        android:title="My Rides" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_licence_details"
        android:title="Licence Details" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_setting"
        android:title="Setting" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_help"
        android:title="Help" />
    **<item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        android:onClick="out"/>**

</group>

<item android:title="Communicate">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_share"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
            android:title="Share" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_send"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:title="Send" />

    </menu>
</item>
```

**Navigation.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_vehicle_enq) {


            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_vehicle) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_rides) {


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_licence_details) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.hp.winnersfive">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".RegisterActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".vehicle_enquiryActivity" />


    </application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully I'm not too late to help...

Ok, so firstly you must declare a onNavigationItemSelected method within the root of the class of the Activity you have the Navigation Drawer in. Then you would need to write a switch statement which adds functionality to each item within the Drawer, as shown below:

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.item_home:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Home", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.item_userProfile:
                Toast.makeText(this, "User Profile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.item_recycleSites_Maps:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Waste and Recycle Sites", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.item_settings:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
                case R.id.item_logOut:
                    logOut();
                    return true;
            }

drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
}
```

The `logOut();`line refers to a method I have created underneath (also within the class root), which looks like this:

```
private void logOut() {
        mAuth.signOut();
        sendToLogin();
    }
```

And finally, `sendToLogin();` is a reference to the last method needed to complete this...

```
private void sendToLogin() {

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();

    }
```

The reason for having created the two additional classes instead of simply writing the Intent within the switch statement is due to good practise, and becomes a lot more practical if you have more than one Navigation Drawer within your application, which in my case is true.

Hope this helps, and if you have any more questions, ask away!

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourLoginActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: have you added listener navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener
to navigation view

Comment: Your java code seems correct, will you please upload your activity_home xml code

Comment: Why asking for xml is make sure your DrawerLayout has only two child and SECOND child should be navigation view

Comment: im new here please tell me where i have to change

Comment: what actually happens when you click on log out

Comment: When I click on logout it is didn't navigate to login page